# Is there an Android Spotify developers API?

Tags: android

I was looking into building an android app that utilizes the Spotify API but when i looked on this page it doesn't list an android API? is there one out there somewhere? if not are there any other streaming music services that have API's for android?

http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/overview/

Comment: Well they provide a c lib for linux/arm. Since android is linux based and most devices are ARM ones I guess you can use that in combination with the android NDK to build a java wrapper api.

Comment: To be honest im really not that advanced yet but thank you. What im really just looking to do is find out what song the spotify is currently playing and also "send" songs to the spotify app to be played

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't appear to be.
You could ask them on [their Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/Spotify) or one of the other links at the bottom right corner of http://developer.spotify.com/en/

Or you could use their [Contact Page](http://www.spotify.com/uk/work-with-us/partners/contact/)

Comment: Please see my answer, this seems to be out of date.

Comment: Look at the comments on the Question. alextsc mentioned the ARM library. Peter responded that he wasn't advanced enough (at the time, at least) to use NDK with ARM.

Answer (score 4):

There is a C library that can be used on ARM android devices. it is available at: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/

Answer (score 0):

Spotify have just released an [Android SDK in Beta](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/). You may want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

the SDK for android:

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/

and the spotify API for streaming, get playlist, songs, user etc...

https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android

the example github use MediaPlayer replace this with spotify.Player when for play you should use Uris of spotify.

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is sdk now [GitHub](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk)